# how to add table view footer with one label in swift 5

Tags: swift, swift5

I want to add only one label at the end of the tableview.

```
let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50))
customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))
label.text = "app version"
customView.addSubview(label)

sideMenuTableView.tableFooterView = customView
```

I want to set the customView width equal to main view's width and label should be at the left most corner of the view

Answer (score 0):

Try this with `mainView` width

```
let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.mainView.frame.size.width, height: 50))
customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.mainView.frame.size.width, height: 50))
label.text = "app version"
label.textAlignment = .left
customView.addSubview(label)

sideMenuTableView.tableFooterView = customView
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

> Add UITableViewDelegate Methods:-

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 40))
        footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        let labelFooter = UILabel(frame: footerView.frame)
        labelFooter.text = "Footer view label text."
        labelFooter.textColor = .red
        footerView.addSubview(labelFooter)
        return footerView
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 40
    }
```

Comment: @sagarmahionwork your welcome :)  upvote my answer. and also approve it so other people get help from it.